# leave-one-out cross validation with multiple regressors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to perform a leave-one-out cross validation on a multiple regression and I got the following script from a forum

```
clc
clear all
close all
warning off
data=readtable('Leave_One_Out.csv');
x=table2array(data(:,1))';
y=table2array(data(:,2))';
n=length(x);
predictions=[];
for p=1:n
    trainindex=setdiff(1:n,p);
    testindex=p;
    xtrain=Z(trainindex);
    ytrain=y(trainindex);
    xtest=Z(testindex);
    a=[];
    for i=1:length(xtrain)
        a=[a ; xtrain(i) 1];
    end
    c =a\ytrain';
    ytest = c(1)*xtest + c(2);
    predictions=[predictions ytest];
end
r=y-predictions;
r=r.^2;
rsq=(1-(sum(r)/sum((y-mean(y)).^2)))*100;
disp(rsq);
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to extend the script to three regressors. Also, I need it to print all the RSQs in a table.

Comment: The question needs a lot more detail and at the moment it's unclear what you have tried, if anything. Here are a few pointers regardless: 1. It's unclear what `Z` is - it looks like a vector of the empirical data - is this correct? 2. I don't think `x` is used anywhere (except to get `n` which is basically trivial and could be attained from `y`)... 3. Why do you make `a` using a `for` loop? It looks like it could be made just by concatenating a vector of ones the same size. Something like `a = [xtrain; ones(size(xtrain))]';`

Comment: 4.  If you want to add more regressors, where will they be read from? If they are in the data table, I imagine you want to add them to `x`. Perhaps something like `x = table2array(data(:,end-1))'; y = table2array(data(:,end))';`. Then, you can try changing the regression code from there.